# Looping ggplot to create multiple plots (issue with geom_errorbar)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using summarySE() to create the mean and standard error of my data set. This data is then plotted using ggplot und geom_errorbar. I'm trying to create plots for >20 different measurements. The loop works all right until I am adding geom_errorbar. It works allright when removing the loop and changing "i" with "pH" or whatever the heading is. Could someone please point me into the right direction?

```
colNames <- names(results)[5:11]

for(i in colNames){
  
  results_summary <- summarySE(results, measurevar = i, groupvars=c("Plot","Treatment"), na.rm="TRUE")
  results_summary$Plot <- factor(results_summary$Plot, levels = c("A","B","C"))
  
  plt <- ggplot(results_summary, aes_string(x="Treatment", y = i, fill = "Plot")) +
    geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour='black')  +
    facet_wrap(~Plot) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=i-se, ymax=i+se), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))
    
  print(plt)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

The error message is:

> Error in i - se : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: It looks as if `i` is a column name, so it’s a character, not a numeric. But you haven’t shared your data, so we can’t be sure. If your data were tidy, you could probably do what you want without the `for` loop. As the name suggests, the tidyverse likes tidy data.

Comment: `i` is a character, i.e. the column name. Hence you get an error. To tell ggplot2 you want the data column with that name you could use the `.data` pronoun inside `aes()`, i.e. do e.g. `ymin = .data[[i]]-se`